# strpos: 2 results but 2 similar strings

Tags: php, string, strpos

I don't know what to do.

2 parameters:
first:

> 0 D:/Google Drive/Dokumente/Programmierung/Webentwicklung/htdocs/BeLL__Webseite_fuer_Filmfestival/php/checkSession.php(6): Phip/Engine/Login->checkSession()
>   1 D:/Google Drive/Dokumente/Programmierung/Webentwicklung/htdocs/BeLL__Webseite_fuer_Filmfestival/login.php(3): include('D:/Google Drive...')
>    {main}

second:

> D:/Google Drive/Dokumente/Programmierung/Webentwicklung/htdocs/BeLL__Webseite_fuer_Filmfestival/php/Phip/Engine/Login/Login.php

php function

```
private function clean( $clean ) {
    $clean = str_replace( '\\', '/', $clean );
    if ( !strpos( $clean, 'D:/Google Drive/Dokumente/Programmierung/Webentwicklung/htdocs/BeLL__Webseite_fuer_Filmfestival' )) {
        return  str_replace( 'D:/Google Drive/Dokumente/Programmierung/Webentwicklung/htdocs/BeLL__Webseite_fuer_Filmfestival', '', $clean );
    } 
}
```

Problem:

**false**: var_dump( !strpos( $param1,  'D:/Google Drive/Dokumente/Programmierung/Webentwicklung/htdocs/BeLL__Webseite_fuer_Filmfestival' ) );

**true**: var_dump( !strpos( $param2,  'D:/Google Drive/Dokumente/Programmierung/Webentwicklung/htdocs/BeLL__Webseite_fuer_Filmfestival' ) );

I can't understand this, because this string is in both strings ... can someone help me please?
Why is this not the same?

Thank you so much! I hope you unterstand what I want.

Comment: Explain what do you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `strpos()` wrongly.

> `strpos()` [finds] the numeric position of the first occurrence of needle in the haystack string.

And more importantly:

> Warning: This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

So use it like:

```
strpos($needle, $haystack) === false // true if needle is not contained in haystack
strpos($needle, $haystack) !== false // true if needle is contained in haystack
```

Comment: +1 for reading the (F) manual on someone else's behalf. It's all written there phip1611. http://us1.php.net/strpos